# Why does joining an array with `printf` give different results in the terminal vs a script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, printf, zsh

I was trying to write a script which involved printing an array with a delimiter. Unfortunately, the `printf` command that worked typing into the command line did not work when run as a script. It also seems that bash and zsh handle things differently.

This gives the intended output, it works if I just paste directly into the terminal like this:

```sh
➜  ~ array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"
a
b
c
d
```

However, when run as a script, the output was not what I wanted:

```sh
➜  ~ echo 'array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"' > test1.sh
➜  ~ bash test1.sh 
abcdn
```

Then I remembered that zsh is my default shell, so I tried running it explicitly with zsh. The results were closer to what I wanted (there was something in between each array element), but still not what I got when pasting into the terminal. Why is the `\` in `\n` ignored in this case?

```sh
➜  ~ zsh test1.sh
anbncndn
```

Also, is there a handy table somewhere of the key differences in basic commands like `echo` and `printf` between shells and in scripts vs the terminal?

EDIT:

I noticed that my example was flawed in that when I created the script `test.sh` file, the echo left out the backslash before the n.

```sh
➜  ~ echo '
array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"
'

array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp %sn "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"
```

But what threw me off was that `zsh -c` showed the same behavior. Is it also stripping out backslashes?

```sh
➜  ~ zsh -c 'array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"'
anbncndn
```

Edit 2: It's that escape characters work in each of these situations.
three preceding backslashes turn in back into a good ol' newline.

```
zsh -c 'array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\\\\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"'
a
b
c
d
```

EDIT3: So the escaping in a script works differently from '-c'

The script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"
```

the result:

```
➜  ~ zsh test.sh     
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
zsh -c 'array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"'
anbncndn
```

In this, the argument to `-c` is split into three parts:

```
'array=()
array+=a
array+=b
array+=c
array+=d
printf -v tmp '
```

```
%s\n
```

and

```
' "${array[@]}"
echo "$tmp"'
```

which are all concatenated together. The sections inside single quotes aren't subject to substitutions, expansions, special handling of backslashes, etc. The middle section *is*, and becomes `%sn` before it's passed to `zsh` for execution. When you add extra backslashes, `%s\\\\n` becomes `%s\\n`, and the double backslash is turned into a single one by the `zsh` executing the command.

In your script, because you're not trying to quote the entire thing to make it a single argument, `printf -v tmp '%s\\n' "${array[@]}"` is split and treated the way you want. However, because you're doubling up the backslash there, `$tmp` is set to `a\nb\nc\nd\n`. Then when you `echo` it, the default `zsh` behavior is to expand backslash escape sequences in the string being printed, so it looks right. This can be disabled with the `BSD_ECHO` shell option, or using `echo -E`. If you want actual newlines, use a single backslash inside single quotes, or a double one inside double quotes or unquoted.

Demonstration:

```
$ printf -v tmp '%s\\n' a b c d
$ echo "$tmp"
a
b
c
d
$ echo -E "$tmp"
a\nb\nc\nd\n
$ setopt BSD_ECHO
$ echo "$tmp"
a\nb\nc\nd\n
$ printf -v tmp '%s\n' a b c d
$ echo "$tmp"
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 4):

`zsh` handles arrays differently than `bash`. In `zsh` (your interactive shell), `array+=b` really does append the string `b` as a new array element.

In `bash`, however, the same command only appends the string `b` to the *first* element of the array; to append a new element, you need to use `array+=(b)`.

Comment: Ok but why does the example explicitly run with zsh also give a different result? That was actually the main part of my question, the bash difference was just something I noticed along the way.

Comment: Because (as I gather you now know, having accepted the other answer) you weren't running the same script in both situations.